# Building enterprise level applications without frontend frameworks

Tags: model-view-controller, frontend

Is it possible to develop very complex applications with just the MVC pattern which returns just Views(dynamic views with html,css & js) or do I need a frontend framework (such as angular) for such applications?

Comment: of course it's possible but you'd be essentially writing your own framework at the end of the day.  And that begs the question of why you would want to do that rather than pursuing one of the existing tried and tested frameworks. FYI, this isn't really an SO appropriate question, as it isn't addressing a specific programming problem.

Comment: You can. But to make your life easy, use a framework :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can, but frameworks are developed to make the developer journey easier, they gives you utilities that otherwise you would need to develop by yourself.

You can develop enterprise application without any framework, but you will need more code and you will need to take care about aspects that a framework already has developed, such routing, http requests etc.